# How do I add data from two tables in mySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with two fields, named `credithour` and `gradepoint`.

I want to add the data from each row of `credithour` with `gradepoint`.

My code :

```
$totalcredithour = 0;                           
$GPA = "SELECT * FROM $dept_stu_id WHERE sessionyear = '$sessionyear'" or die (mysql_error());
$resultGPA = mysql_query($GPA);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($resultGPA))
{ 
    $credithour = "$data[credithour]";
    $gradepoint = "$data[gradepoint]";
    echo $totalcredithour += $credithour;   
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

It added data, but showing the first credit hour also besides result.
Suppose, here i entered two data 3 and 5. When I run this code it echo 38. Which means "3+5=8" and 1st credithour = "3".

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but it wasn't very clear to begin with. Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: i want to retrieve the data from two column, and add each row of data from those column separately. That is i try to doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually other answer are wrong, you're doing `or die(mysql_error());` next to a string, that's not right.

Your code should be like this..

```
$totalcredithour = 0;                           
$GPA = "SELECT * FROM `".$dept_stu_id."` WHERE sessionyear = `".$sessionyear."` ";
$resultGPA = mysql_query($GPA) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($resultGPA, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ 
    $credithour = $data['credithour'];
    $gradepoint = $data['gradepoint'];

    echo $totalcredithour += $credithour; //Make sure `$totalcredithot` isn't null/doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't working. Yes, "$totalcredithour" is exist and null.

Comment: Weird, make sure those columns exists. Also, change `echo $totalcredithour += $credithour;` to `echo $credithour;`. So we can check if it's returning null.

Comment: yeah, I have already change that and returning same result. I agree, its weird. I have just edited my post, see that please. Thnx

Comment: I got it. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in your while loop:

```
$credithour = $data['credithour'];
$gradepoint = $data['gradepoint'];
```

Comment: is your table called $dept_stu_id?  it might just be dept_stu_id - the $ designates a php variable.

Comment: Nope, "$dept_stu_id" is a posted variable, which i used as a table name. It isn't a related about this problem dear.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

I have edited the answer and added the floatval function

```
$totalcredithour = 0;                           
  $GPA = "SELECT * FROM `".$dept_stu_id."` WHERE sessionyear = '".$sessionyear."'" or die (mysql_error());
 $resultGPA = mysql_query($GPA);
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($resultGPA))
{ 
$credithour = $data['credithour'];
$gradepoint = $data['gradepoint'];
echo $totalcredithour += floatval($credithour);   
 }
```

Comment: The related data are retrieve successfully, but problem is they don't add. :(